# Should I set ini_set() on every page of my websites or will it on the first page do?

Tags: php, ini-set

I want to set two ini directives by ini_set():

```
ini_set("session.cookie_httponly","1");
```

and

```
if(/*cookies disabled*/){
    ini_set("session.use_only_cookies", "0");
    $url.=htmlspecialchars(SID);
}
```

Will it work to set it just on the first page (especially the first one) or should I provide it on every page of my project?

And if I should use it on every page: Is there any other option to change configuration settings if I haven't got the access to the `php.ini` and PHP configuration files on the server? Could I set it in other way? (e.g. by using another PHP function or `.htaccess`)

Comment: Stuff like that should be in a `config.php` file that you `include` at the start of pages.

Comment: Looks like easy and clear solution, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want those settings to apply to every page request you need that code to be present on every page. Placing it in one file and then using `require()` to include it would be the best way to handle it in your situation.

You can try to [set these values in your htaccess file](http://davidwalsh.name/php-values-htaccess) but many web hosts disable this.

Comment: I found, that just FastCGI installed PHP doesn't accept .htaccess settings, thanks. I think I'll rather try to create `config.php` file from @Niet the Dark Absol recommendation

Comment: Well, I checked whether my hosting uses PHP as FastCGI and not, so finally, .htaccess is the best option for me, many thanks